# How do I apply a monkeypatch to GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can you tell me how I apply this patch to google app engine as in where to put it? Thank you

```
def _user_init(self, email=None, _auth_domain=None,
             _user_id=None, federated_identity=None, federated_provider=None):
  if not _auth_domain:
    _auth_domain = os.environ.get('AUTH_DOMAIN')
  assert _auth_domain

  if email is None and federated_identity is None:
    email = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL', email)
    _user_id = os.environ.get('USER_ID', _user_id)
    federated_identity = os.environ.get('FEDERATED_IDENTITY',
                                        federated_identity)
    federated_provider = os.environ.get('FEDERATED_PROVIDER',
                                        federated_provider)

  if not email and not federated_identity:
    raise UserNotFoundError

  self.__email = email
  self.__federated_identity = federated_identity
  self.__federated_provider = federated_provider
  self.__auth_domain = _auth_domain
  self.__user_id = _user_id or None

users.User.__init__ = _user_init
```

Comment: `monkeypatch` != `patch`. Which is it?

Comment: It's called monkeypatch where we received it as a solution here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/ClkOIalYD3s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it as-is: Put that code in a module that gets imported before you use the relevant User module or datastore functionality. I included the relevant line to patch the code (the last line) with the patch itself.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the constructor like this is not safe. If the internal implementation of the Users API changes in production, your application could break without warning.

What are you trying to accomplish here? I don't see any custom logic; it looks like you've just copied the constructor from the SDK verbatim. If you need to add custom logic, try subclassing UserProperty and/or wrapping the users API calls instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Here's a link to the background where Nick Johnson sent us this as a patch https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/ClkOIalYD3s

Comment: Thanks, that's relevant. You basically just need to include this in your own code, after you've imported users but before you first instantiate a User object. E.g., at the top of your main.py, after imports.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this belongs to some application as a grep within the appengine sdk, for 'federated_identity' does not result any clues. BTW, you should be doing the same. Grep (or WinGrep) for terms like 'federated' to see if this partial patch can be applied to any source.

Thanks for the updated link. The patch can be added to the file  [google/appengine/api/users.py](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/users.py)

You might just need to add the last line: `users.User.__init__ = _user_init`

I could figure this out after checking the latest code in the svn.

Comment: We received the code as a patch to an unknown problem here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/ClkOIalYD3s

Comment: Don't modify the SDK. The whole point of the monkeypatch is that it fixes a bug without modifying the SDK.