# Help with error message

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

There's an error message I can't understand since I don't see where my code calls it. It appears when using the User object with Google app engine with `dev_appserver`. Can you tell me what it means?

```
ERROR    2011-07-15 15:01:07,664 __init__.py:463] 'User' object has no attribute '_User__email'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 700, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/myproject/i18n.py", line 313, in get
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 73, in render
    return t.render(Context(template_dict))
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 115, in wrap_render
    return orig_render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 139, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 258, in render
    return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 849, in render
    return _render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/template/__init__.py", line 829, in _render_value_in_context
    value = force_unicode(value)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/lib/django_1_2/django/utils/encoding.py", line 66, in force_unicode
    s = unicode(s)
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 188, in __unicode__
    return unicode(self.nickname())
  File "/media/Lexar/projects/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 152, in nickname
    if (self.__email and self.__auth_domain and
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_User__email'
```

EDIT: The error goes away when I remove this code:

`'user_url': users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else 'login','user' : users.get_current_user(),`

So supposedly I'm making some mistake using the User object

UPDATE: It's seems to have something to do with a monkeypatch I applied. Removing this part removes the error so I'm wondering whether I still need this patch. It's reported in

```
def _user_init(self, email=None, _auth_domain=None,
             _user_id=None, federated_identity=None, federated_provider=None,
             _strict_mode=True):

  if not _auth_domain:
    _auth_domain = os.environ.get('AUTH_DOMAIN')
  assert _auth_domain

  if email is None and federated_identity is None:
    email = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL', email)
    _user_id = os.environ.get('USER_ID', _user_id)
    federated_identity = os.environ.get('FEDERATED_IDENTITY',
                                        federated_identity)
    federated_provider = os.environ.get('FEDERATED_PROVIDER',
                                        federated_provider)

  if not email and not federated_identity and _strict_mode:
    raise UserNotFoundError

  self.__email = email
  self.__federated_identity = federated_identity
  self.__federated_provider = federated_provider
  self.__auth_domain = _auth_domain
  self.__user_id = _user_id or None

users.User.__init__ = _user_init
```

Related thread where the monkeypatch comes from
[How do I apply a monkeypatch to GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912462/how-do-i-apply-a-monkeypatch-to-gae)

Comment: I'm puzzled by the info in your UPDATE. The patch seems to *always* assign a value to `User.__email` (=`User._User__email`), so I'm surprised that you get a `User` object without it. For a minute I pondered if you could have applied the patch the wrong way around, but then *removing* it should not have solved the issue... Puzzling indeed... :-/

Comment: I'm also puzzled what the code does and whether I should keep it. I didn't understand the code, I was just needed to get pasted and now I don't now whether to onclude it anymore since that issue might have been addressed by the SDK.

Comment: My philosophy is that if the code passes the tests it is designed for and the patch doesn't address a security issue, I never patch. The reason is that sometimes patches subtly affect the working of other parts of the code (as it seems it's the case for you), and you can easily end up having code that will break on upgrading to a version of the main software where the patch won't be needed any longer. This is one of the many reasons for which I'm in love with test-driven development, btw! :)

Comment: Thanks mac for the insights. I commented out the old patch that I previously used to handle a so-called corrupt userproperty that reportedly really was due to a bug in the nvironment. Now the SDK upgrades seem to have addressed the problem and everything appears to be running smoothly again. You may have a look at my site http://koolbusiness.com I also keep the code open source: http://montao.googlecode.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess your error is at import-time of some module:

```
ERROR    2011-07-15 15:01:07,664 __init__.py:463] 'User' object has no attribute '_User__email'
```

`__init__.py` is the file that define a directory as being a package of modules.

You could either look for a line #463 with a `User` object on it, or selectively removing the imports for understanding which package is at fault.

I would guess that for fixing it, you need to make sure when the `User` object does have a `_User__email` (which is the [mangled name](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) of `__email`) attribute, but not knowing how you make the call that generate the mistake it's difficult to say...

Comment: Just fyi, the `_User__email` attribute is generated by python's [double-underscore name mangling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) from the definition of `User.__email`.

Comment: The error goes away if I don't use the user object ie if I comment out using the User object the error is gone: `...'user_url': users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else 'login','user' : users.get_current_user(),...`

Comment: @senderle - good point, I included it in the answer directly.